# Hierarchial query missing result

Tags: oracle

i have an Oracle hierarchical query that looks like it will answer what i need. The issue i see with it is that the parent 187091 is not shown in the LEVEL_SAMPLE_NUMBER field.

How would I modify this query to allow the parent 187091 to show in the LEVEL_SAMPLE_NUMBER field?

[image]

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) and [this too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Comment: Thanks ypercube, that was the issue the sample.status was different than what I used.